# Create sub-tags in Matlab Soap request

Tags: web-services, matlab, soap

I am developing a SOAP client in Matlab for connection a Web Service. What I am doing is the following script:

```
createClassFromWsdl('http://192.168.107.239/WSDL/v4.0/iLON100.wsdl')
obj = iLON100
methods(obj)
```

With the next result:

```
Methods for class iLON100:

Clear      Get        List       Set        display    
Delete     InvokeCmd  Read       Write      iLON100
```

Then, I am editing for example the method List in order to request the list of Items for the service. The dot m file is:

```
% Build up the argument lists.
values = { '','//Item[@xsi:type="Dp_Cfg"]'};
names = { 'iLonItem','xSelect'};
types = {};

% Create the message, make the call, and convert the response into a variable.
soapMessage = createSoapMessage('http://wsdl.echelon.com/web_services_ns/ilon100/v4.0/message/', 
'List', values, names, types, 'document');
```

I have also a SOAP tester from the vendor of the device. Then, if I compare both XML requests, they differ as you can see in the next example (firstly the original request and secondly the Matlab one):

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<List xmlns="http://wsdl.echelon.com/web_services_ns/ilon100/v4.0/message/">
   <iLonItem>
      <xSelect>
         //Item[@xsi:type="Dp_Cfg"]
      </xSelect>
   </iLonItem>
</List>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>



<soap:Body soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <List xmlns="http://wsdl.echelon.com/web_services_ns/ilon100/v4.0/message/">
     <iLonItem/>
     <xSelect>Item</xSelect>
   </List>
</soap:Body>
```

As you can observe, the tags are not included as sub-tags. I would like to know how to do it and generate the same structure of XML for sending the SOAP request correctly.

Thank you so much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I have solved it by creating a structure as follows:

```
myStruct = struct('iLonItem',struct('xSelect','//Item[@xsi:type="Dp_Cfg"]'))
```

This structure is inserted into "values" and the method's name "iLONItem".